# Are green clay cataplasms effective to treat tendinitis?

Tags: medical-science, natural-remedies

I have heard and read from various (low quality) sources that green clay [cataplasms](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cataplasm) are effective to treat [tendinitis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tendinitis) (a.k.a. tendonitis). E.g.:

- [Argiletz](http://www.argiletz.com/en/tips/how-to-use-clay):

  > Green clay can be used for healing bruises and relieving pain in
  >   children and grown-ups: rheumatism, sustained effort, long walks
  >   (soothes sore feet), tendinitis, back pain...
- [Hope For Health](http://hopeforhealth.webs.com/greenclayinstructions.htm):

  > Pain Relief, Anti-Inflammatory Action, and Swelling Reduction. Helpful For tendinitis.
- [Hawaii Naturopathic Retreat](http://www.hawaiinaturopathicretreat.com/treatments/clay-packs/):

  > Tendonitis
  >
  > Clay wrap around entire area if possible, 1/4 – 1/2 inch thick,
  >   covered, for 20 minutes to an hour initially, increased to overnight
  >   applications as tolerance permits, for three days to three weeks.

Are there any studies on green clay cataplasms' effectiveness to treat tendinitis?

I am aware of the existence of question [Does eating clay have any beneficial effect?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10923/7654), but I'm interested in the external use of green clay, not internal.

Answer (score 1):

There are no studies on PubMed with the terms "clay, poultice and tendintis/tendonitis" so we can conclude that there has been no peer reviewed published research in this area to support the claims.

Medline Plus advises on the management of tendinitis [1]

> Rest or immobilization of the affected tendons is helpful for
>   recovery. This may be achieved using a splint or a removable brace.
>   The application of heat or cold to the affected area can help.

So, if the green clay poultice provides immobilization with some heat, it might conceivably help.

[1] http://www.nlm.nih.gov/medlineplus/ency/article/001229.htm